# jquery slideUp slideDown form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the Appointment Form to be in the down position when the page loads. When the "Make an Appointment" button is clicked, the form should slide up.

This is the code

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Appointment Form
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$('.make-appoint').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var appointment_form = $this.parents('.appointment').find('.appointment-form');
    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
        appointment_form.slideDown(500);
        $this.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        appointment_form.slideUp(500);
        $this.addClass('open');
    }
});
```

This is the form

http://kdg.vnd-ink.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery slideUp/slideDown issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746536/jquery-slideup-slidedown-issue)

Comment: $(function(){
      $('.make-appoint').addClass('open').parents('.appointment').find('.appointment-form').hide();
});...

Comment: it is working as you expected... whats wrong!!

Comment: By _down position_ what do you mean?? Where exactly you wanna keep it??

Comment: Appears to work OK? http://jsfiddle.net/vrvf6jLk/